# LINQ query help

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections

```
List<CustomClass1> items1 
List<CustomClass2> items2

CustomClass1 has a property KEY
CustomClass2 has a property KEY
```

i want to keep only those entries in items1 which have a matching key in items2. How can this be achieved through LINQ?

thanks

Comment: @six: I think [tag:linq-to-objects] should still apply here.  This specifically is using LINQ to objects and methods used here _might_ not apply to other providers.

Comment: @Jeff: I figured it was implied given he has two `List<T>`s. I won't object to it being re-tagged as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var res = items1.Where(a=> items2.Any(c=>c.Key == a.Key));
```

Comment: thanks.. will this modify the original collection .. i mean items1.

Comment: no, it doesn't. No standard (as in: from the .net framework) LINQ operator modifies the original collection.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado Could you briefly explain your performance concerns here? I'm just curious.

Comment: @asawyer: This right off the bat would become a `O(n*m)` operation.  For every item in `items1`, we're performing a (linear) search in `items2`.  Using a join on the other hand could be (and probably is) optimized to do some hashing.  So I would avoid this approach if I had the choice.

Answer (score 4):

```
var res = items1.Join(items2,
                      item1 => item1.Key, 
                      item2 => item2.Key, 
                      (item1, item2) => item1);
```

Comment: When they ask for LINQ, actually *use* LINQ itself please! :\ Not just the methods.

Comment: @Megrdad This is perfectly valid Linq code. It's Lambda syntax instead of query syntax thats all.

Comment: @asawyer: But AFAIK "LINQ" means "language-integrated query", and from what I see, there's nothing different about this language than normal C#.

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from i1 in items1 
        join i2 in items2 on i1.Key equals i2.Key 
        select i1;
```

Comment: @Mehrdad It's interesting that these are all pretty much the same, this should compile to something like Femaref's answer.

Comment: Yes, this translates to my query.

Comment: @asawyer: Yeah they compile to pretty much the same thing, except that yours uses LINQ (i.e. language-integrate query) whereas Femaref's doesn't.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's all LINQ.  Using the query syntax doesn't make it more LINQy than not.  LINQ isn't just about the syntax, but also the libraries that back it up.

Comment: @Mehrdad You may have a slight misconception on what is and is not Linq.

Comment: Nope Mehrdad. This is the query syntax, mine is the method chain syntax. LINQ is both.

Comment: Eh, whatever... I'm just being .picky I guess. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the Intersect operator-

```
var result = item1.Intersect(item2);
```

If necessary the overload allows an equity comparer, although if your items are from the same context it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: It only works if they are collections of the same type.  They are not in the question however.

Comment: And you are completely correct.. missed that the collections were different types. Thanks!